# Get-AutomationConnection not working as per MS Docs

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-automation

When I am using the cmdlet

```
$Conn = Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection
Connect-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $Conn.TenantID 
-ApplicationId $Conn.ApplicationID -CertificateThumbprint $Conn.CertificateThumbprint
```

to authenticate my azure resource. I am not able to find `-Tenant` and `$conn.TenantID` ,`$Conn.ApplicationID` is not found by intelligent either.

Doc referred: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-first-runbook-textual-powershell"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First `Get-AutomationConnection` is used in automation runbooks alone to retrieve data from Azure Automation internally, You can't run this in local PowerShell.

If you see the **Note** in the same [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-first-runbook-textual-powershell") which you are referring,

> Important
>
> **Add-AzureRmAccount** and **Login-AzureRmAccount** are now aliases for
>   **Connect-AzureRMAccount**. If the Connect-AzureRMAccount cmdlet **does not
>   exist**, you can use **Add-AzureRmAccount** or **Login-AzureRmAccount**, or you
>   can update your modules in your Automation Account to the latest
>   versions.

So instead of `Connect-AzureRMAccount` you can use either `Add-AzureRmAccount/Login-AzureRmAccount`

Make sure you import the **`AzureRM.Profile`** Module to your Automation account.

Coming back to your question

The `$conn.TenantID` ,`$Conn.ApplicationID` will be *automatically* retrieved by Azure based on your Automation Account *credentials*. (You don't need to give any values for this Parameters)

### How to find the tenant Id?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jay, this is really helpful !!

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct, but please make sure:

- you are invoking this code from an Automation runbook, not from a stand-alone PS session; and
- your Automation account has a [connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-connections) asset named "AzureRunAsConnection". The easiest way to create this connection asset is to specify "Create Azure Run As account: YES" when you create an Automation account.